# Function to find value in another column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a "menu" sheet set up in a work book. It has two columns.  Column A are locations.  Dallas, Austin, etc. Column B are drop down menus that are Yes or No.

I am looking to develop a function where I can search through column B. If the cell in column B is yes, it grabs the value from column A.  If it is set to No, it continues along to the next row.

Those cities and column A are also functions. So if Column B says yes, it runs function Dallas();

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you need FILTER:

```
=FILTER(menu!A:A; menu!B:B="yes")
```

Comment: Thank you but I am looking to program this.